# Не работает програма которая должна загружать картинки с сайта!

Tags: python, python-3.x

Програма должна загружать картинки с сайта но при запуске програми выдает такую ошибку !(Не нашёл решения проблемы в интернете!)``

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import *

url = 'https://wallhaven.cc/search?q=id:55&ref=fp'


def get_html(url, req, html):
    req = request(url)
    html = urlopen(req).read()
    return html


def main() -> object:
    opener = build_opener()
    opener.addheaders = [('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
    install_opener(opener)
    for i in range(1, 2):
        html = get_html(url + str(i))
        soup = BeautifulSaup(html, 'html.parser')
        list = soup.find_all(class_='preview')
        for a in list:
            secondary_html = get_html(a['href'])
            secondary_soup = BeautifulSaup(secondary_html, 'html.parser')
            image = secondary_soup.find(id='wallpaper')['srk']
            urlretrieve('https:' + image, image[52:])
            print(str(index), image[52:], 'Был скачан')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(url)
```

[image: Вот такая проблема]

Comment: 1. Никогда не называйте функцию именем main. переименуйте  `def main()` во что-то другое и укажите аргумент, например `def myfunc(url)`. 2. после строки с  `if __name__` вызывайте свою функцию `myfunc(url)`, а не `main()`.

Comment: для начало просто main()

Comment: @strawdog, а почему вы считаете, что функции не стоит называть `main`? :)

Comment: В строках неверно написано название класса
Вот верный вариант:
`soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')`
`secondary_soup = BeautifulSoup(secondary_html, 'html.parser')`

Comment: @strawdog совсем наоборот. Традиционно такую функцию и называют именно main().

Comment: По моему мнение функцией `main` стоит называть то ,что можно(или следует)  записаться в `if __name__ == "__main__":` . А это действительно лучше назвать `loadimg(url) `.

Answer (score 2):

Иногда полезно читать текст ошибки. В этой, например, написано, что функция `main()` не принимает аргументов, а вы в неё запихиваете аргумент `url`

Возможные решения, которые напрашиваются сами собой:

1. Изменить саму функцию, включив в неё аргумент
2. Не передавать аргумент `url` при вызове функции `main`

Сам выбор напрямую зависит от того, что вы хотите получить в итоге - в саму функцию я не вчитывался, просто рассказал смысл ошибки и предложил все варианты решения.

Comment: Ответы практически одинаковые(этот немного лучше)

Comment: И дан на минуту раньше
Но да, разницы особой нет - просто у человека была подобная проблема 14 часов назад, но он её так и не осознал...

Comment: Вообще вопрос "не по теме".Последнюю строчку
текста ошибки следует читать.Прочитал ,понял и воскликнул:"Да тут все очевидно!"

Answer (score 0):

У тебя функция main не принимает никаких параметров, но ты всё равно их передаёшь,
поменяй `def main()` на `def main(url)`

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests


def get_html(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    return response.text


def main():
    url = 'https://wallhaven.cc/search?q=id:55&ref=fp'


    html = get_html(url)
    soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
    list = soup.find_all("a", attrs={"class": "preview"})#содержит ссылки на страницы, где храняться картинки
    for i, link in enumerate(list):
        html = get_html(link.get('href'))
        soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
        img = soup.find('img', attrs={"id": "wallpaper"}).get('src')
        p = requests.get(img)
        out = open(f"img{i}.jpg", "wb")
        out.write(p.content)
        out.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```